# My ajax code is creating 3 records

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following code:

Controller:

```
def create
    @booking = Booking.new
    @booking.book_date      = params[:date_id]
    @booking.teacher        = params[:teacher_id]
    @booking.kid            = params[:student_id]
    @booking.order_blabloo  = sprintf '%012d', Booking.count + 1

    random_number           = rand(36**12).to_s(36) 

    if Booking.where(order_number: random_number)
      random_number         = rand(36**12).to_s(36)
    end

    @booking.order_number   =  random_number

    if @booking.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: @booking.to_json, success: :ok }
          end
    end
  end
```

javascript:

```
$("#btn-confirm").submit(function () {

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data: {"date_id" : date_id, "teacher_id" : teacher_id, "student_id" : student_id},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
      alert("prueba");
    },
    error: function() {

    }
  });
});
```

But it's saving the same record 3 times. I don't understand why?

Any Idea? Thanks for your help.

UPDATE

---

[image]

UPDATE

---

this is the js code of this view

```
:javascript

var date_id, teacher_id, student_id;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-student').click(function(e) {  
    if ($(this).data('img-url') == "missing_avatar_home.png"){
      $("#student-image").attr("src","/assets/missing_avatar_home.png");
      $("#student-name").text($(this).data('student-name'));
    } else {
      $("#student-image").attr("src",$(this).data('img-url'));
      $("#student-name").text($(this).data('student-name')); 
    }
    student_id = $(this).data('student-id');
    $("#student_id").val(student_id);
    $("#details").show();
    $("#students").hide();
    $("#change-student").click(function(){
      $("#students").show();
    });
  });

  function getUrlParameter(sParam)
  {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
      var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
      if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
      {
        return sParameterName[1];
      }
    }
  }
  date_id = getUrlParameter('date_id');
  teacher_id    = getUrlParameter('teacher_id');
  $("#teacher_id").val(teacher_id);
  $("#date_id").val(date_id);

});

$("#btn-confirm").submit(function () {

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data: {"date_id" : date_id, "teacher_id" : teacher_id, "student_id" : student_id},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
      $(this).find(":submit").attr('value','Redirecting!');
    },
    error: function() {

    }
  });
});
```

UPDATE 3

---

I made some change:

Model:

```
class Booking
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :book_date
  field :teacher
  field :order_number
  field :order_blabloo 

  belongs_to :kid

  validates_presence_of   :book_date, :teacher, :order_number, :order_blabloo
  validates_length_of :order_number, :minimum => 4, :maximum => 12
  validates_uniqueness_of :book_date

  attr_accessible :book_date, :teacher

end
```

Controller:

```
class Dashboard::BookingsController < Dashboard::ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @class_date = Availability.find(params[:date_id]) rescue  nil
    @childs = Kid.where(parent_email: current_kid.email)
    @teacher = Kid.find(params[:teacher_id])
    #error
  end

  def create
    @booking = Booking.new
    @booking.book_date      = params[:date_id]
    @booking.teacher        = params[:teacher_id]
    @booking.kid            = params[:student_id]
    @booking.order_blabloo  = sprintf '%012d', Booking.count + 1

    random_number           = rand(36**12).to_s(36) 

    if Booking.where(order_number: random_number)
      random_number         = rand(36**12).to_s(36)
    end

    @booking.order_number   =  random_number

    if @booking.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: @booking.to_json, success: :ok }
          end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    end
end
```

View:

```
%br
%br
%br
- if @class_date.nil?
  .row
    .col-md-12
      .panel.panel-default
        .panel-heading
          %h1.box-title
            %i.fa.fa-calendar
              Please select the day/time for the class by clicking on a green cell below
        .panel-body
          #calendar

          %script(type="text/javascript")
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: [
            - @teacher.availabilities.order("availability_date desc").each do |availability|
              - if (Booking.where(book_date: availability.id.to_s).first)
                {
                title: "No Available",
                start: "#{availability.availability_date.to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")}",
                end:   "#{availability.end_availability_date.to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")}",
                color  : '#66CCFF'
                },
              - else
                {
                title: "Available",
                start: "#{availability.availability_date.to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")}",
                end:   "#{availability.end_availability_date.to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")}",
                url: "/dashboard/kids/jean_oso/bookings/new?date_id=#{availability.id}&teacher_id=#{@teacher.id}",
                },
            ],
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'
            });
            });

- if !@class_date.nil?
  .row#students
    .col-md-12
      .panel.panel-default
        .panel-heading
          %h1.box-title
            %i.fa.fa-child
              = _("Please select the student for this class")
        .panel-body
          .row
            .col-lg-12
              .row
                .col-lg-4
                  .panel.panel-default
                    .panel-heading
                      %h1.box-title
                        %i.fa.fa-child.fa-fw
                        = "#{current_kid.full_name}"
                    .panel-body
                      .row
                        .col-md-6
                          .center
                            = image_tag(current_kid.avatar.url(:home), class: "profile-image", style: "border-radius:50%;border: 2px solid #4b3087;box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;")
                        .col-md-6
                          .pull-right
                            = "#{current_kid.full_name}"
                            %br
                            %br
                            .btn.btn-success.btn-xs.btn-student{ 'data-img-url' => "#{current_kid.avatar.url(:home)}", 'data-student-name' => "#{current_kid.full_name}", 'data-student-id' => "#{current_kid.id}" }
                              %i.fa.fa-heart
                                = _('For you')
                - @childs.each do |child|
                  .col-lg-4
                    .panel.panel-default
                      .panel-heading
                        %h1.box-title
                          %i.fa.fa-child.fa-fw
                          = "#{child.full_name}"
                      .panel-body
                        .row
                          .col-md-6
                            .center
                              = image_tag(child.avatar.url(:home), class: "profile-image", style: "border-radius:50%;border: 2px solid #4b3087;box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;")
                          .col-md-6
                            .pull-right
                              = "#{child.full_name}"
                              %br
                              %br
                              .btn.btn-success.btn-xs.btn-student{ 'data-img-url' => "#{child.avatar.url(:home)}", 'data-student-name' => "#{child.full_name}", 'data-student-id' => "#{child.id}" }
                                %i.fa.fa-heart
                                  = _('For your child')

.row#details{style: "display:none;"}
  .col-md-12
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
        %h1.box-title
          %i.fa.fa-book
            = _("Class Details")
      .panel-body
        .row
          .col-lg-12
            .row
              .col-lg-4
                .panel.panel-default
                  .panel-body
                    %h6
                      = _("What?  60 minutes of     private class")
                    %h6
                      = _("When?  #{@class_date.availability_date.strftime("%A %d, %B %H:%M %p")}") unless @class_date.nil?
                    %h6
                      = _("How    much? 25€")
                    %br
              .col-lg-4
                .panel.panel-default
                  .panel-body
                    .row
                      .col-md-6
                        .center
                          = image_tag(@teacher.avatar.url(:home), class: "profile-image", style: "border-radius:50%;border: 2px solid #4b3087;box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;")
                      .col-md-6
                        .pull-right
                          = _("Teacher")
                          %br
                          = _("#{@teacher.full_name}")
              .col-lg-4
                .panel.panel-default
                  .panel-body
                    .row
                      .col-md-6
                        .center
                          %img.profile-image{:alt => "Missing_avatar_home", :src => "/assets/missing_avatar_home.png", :style => "border-radius:50%;border: 2px solid #4b3087;box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;", id: "student-image"}
                      .col-md-6
                        .pull-right
                          = _("Student")
                          %br
                          %span#student-name
                            = _("#{@teacher.full_name}")
                          %br
                          %span#change-student{style: "cursor: pointer"}
                            = _("Change Student")
            .row
              .col-lg-12
                = form_tag dashboard_kid_bookings_url(current_kid), :method => 'post', id: "save-booking-order", remote: true do
                  .form-group
                    = hidden_field_tag 'teacher_id', ''
                    = hidden_field_tag 'date_id',    ''
                    = hidden_field_tag 'student_id', ''
                  .form-group
                    = submit_tag _('Confirm'),  class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', id: "btn-confirm"
                %br
                .pull-left
                  %span#change-date-time{style: "cursor: pointer"}
                    %a{href: "/dashboard/kids/jean_oso/bookings/new?&teacher_id=#{@teacher.id}"}
                      = _("Change date/time")
                .pull-right
                  %a{href: dashboard_online_classes_url}
                    = ("Cancel")
      .panel-footer
        = _("Once you hit the “Confirm” button, you will be redirected to a secured bank payment platform where you will introduce your credit/debit card details.")
        %br
        = _("Blabloo does not handle any of your card details.")          


:javascript

  var date_id, teacher_id, student_id;

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-student').click(function(e) {  
      if ($(this).data('img-url') == "missing_avatar_home.png"){
        $("#student-image").attr("src","/assets/missing_avatar_home.png");
        $("#student-name").text($(this).data('student-name'));
      } else {
        $("#student-image").attr("src",$(this).data('img-url'));
        $("#student-name").text($(this).data('student-name')); 
      }
      student_id = $(this).data('student-id');
      $("#student_id").val(student_id);
      $("#details").show();
      $("#students").hide();
      $("#change-student").click(function(){
        $("#students").show();
      });
    });

  function getUrlParameter(sParam)
  {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
      var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
      if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
      {
        return sParameterName[1];
      }
    }
  }
  date_id = getUrlParameter('date_id');
  teacher_id    = getUrlParameter('teacher_id');
  $("#teacher_id").val(teacher_id);
  $("#date_id").val(date_id);

  });

  $("#btn-confirm").click(function () {
    $(this).attr('value','Redirecting!');
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: "POST",
      data: {"date_id" : date_id, "teacher_id" : teacher_id, "student_id" : student_id},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result){
        alert("prueba");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Lo Salvo pero dio Error");
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  });
```

Now I save only one record, but the ajax it's executed 3 times, also the ajax always enter in the error section. I attached a image of my developer tool:

[image]

As you can see I have a 404 error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE 5

---

```
$("#btn-confirm").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('value','Redirecting!');
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: "POST",
      data: {"date_id" : date_id, "teacher_id" : teacher_id, "student_id" : student_id},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result){
        alert("prueba");
      },
      error: function(result) {
        alert("Lo Salvo pero dio Error");
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  });
```

after this change, now I get:

[image]

Comment: see how many ajax requests are made in browser console network tab. Possible event handler being bound to element more than once?

Comment: I saw 3 times on my console, as you can see on the image

Comment: Please provide your whole javascript-code since it is most likly triggering your submit 3 times due to other event listeners

Comment: And please also provide HTML!

Comment: Most likely the block of code containing the event handling code is being run 3 different times. That would apply 3 different event handlers that do exactly the same thing

Comment: Umm. 3 keys and three updates. What is happening in your controller? Seems like you are iterating the keys.

Comment: I just discovered that all my ajax run 3 times :S what can I check???

Comment: Still, possible to provide html rendered in browser, not in your code?

Comment: @SSA I can't stackoverflow said that too many characters

Comment: @SSA try to download from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzi-ePCA0wKna0c4bm11SkZJNXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok got it, Where did you add the jquery script? I see 3 times, analytics.js, what is in there? Did you try $("#btn-confirm").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();

Comment: @SSA done, now it's executed one time, but I always get 404 and no record on my database. I attached another image.

Comment: post request making it look like a get (querystring appended). Can you try adding contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', in ajax request.

Comment: @SSA Now I get error 500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61356/discussion-between-ssa-and-jean).

Answer (score -1):

Random number? Surely having your order number random could mean duplicate order numbers? Set the order_id to increment in the db

```
@booking.order_number   =  random_number
```